# Updating an existing row in a table-striped table within an html page

Tags: html, flask

I have the following table structure on my HTML page:

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>field1</th>
        <th>field2</th>
        <th>field3</th>
        <th>field4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for msg in msgs %}
    <tr><td>{{ msg.field1 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field2 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field3 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field4 }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
```

Now every time a msg comes in and is parsed, a new row is added to the table. I would like to define a primary-key of sorts (like in SQL) and have a row added to the table only if there is no existing row with that primary key. If however, there is a row with that primary key, I would like to update the values in that row, rather than creating a new row.

I am new to HTML and am unaware on how this can be done. Any help will be massively appreciated!

Comment: Need a little more information. What's putting the new `msg`s onto the page? Javascript? Can you share that code as well?

Comment: the `msg` data structure is a simple python class object with the fields as attributes.

Comment: @jack To answer your question about what puts the data into the page, its basically a Redis server instance that stores the python dict key, value pairs. And all the code ends up doing is using `Flask`'s `render_template` to render an html template which contains the above html in the original question.

Comment: It'd probably be worth adding extra tags to this particularly `flask`

Comment: You'll probably be needing an `AJAX` request too, to update the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `msg` contains the `id`, you can insert the message primary key or other identifying figure in an `id` tag

```
<tr id="msg-{{ msg.id }}"><td>{{ msg.field1 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field2 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field3 }}</td><td>{{ msg.field4 }}</td>
```

You can then reference the `tr` in the DOM with the `id` tag. How you do that depends on how you are updating the rows in the first place. But you can reference the `id` with `#msg-1`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I will surely try adding an `id` tag like you have suggested and try referencing the row using that tag. You also mentioned about an `AJAX` request. I am new to web programming, and  do not quite understand how these things tie in together. Could you illustrate what exactly you mean?

Comment: That would be too broad an answer for this question, you'd be best to google Flask and AJAX, try to get something working then ask a new more specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: I have a follow up question for you. Can you tell me what you meant by `you can reference the id with #msg-1.` ?

Comment: Sure, if you were using a library like jQuery to help you interact with the DOM you can use the `#` sign to indicate that you are targeting an `id` https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/ in the same way you could use `#` to target an `id` in CSS

Comment: Or if you were using straight JavaScript this gives a good overview of how to interact with the DOM and what the DOM is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: For comparison in jQuery you could write something like this `$("#myDiv")` while in JavaScript it would be like this `document.getElementById("myDiv")` to reference `<div id="myDiv"></div>`

Comment: Great! I will surely give these a shot. However, since I am actually trying to update a table by firstly searching for the `tr` with the id I provide, and then updating a `td` in that `tr` with my value, you think this approach would still help? Much appreciate all your help thus far!

Comment: You would use AJAX to make an asynchronous call to get new data to populate the table. But you'll need to do a little research to work out how to do that for your purposes.

Comment: Yes this is the way to go, you can find elements within a tag once you find it, but like I say this becoming a broad topic. You'll need to research selecting elements in the DOM and how to perform AJAX requests with either jQuery or JavaScript. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will mark this as answered once I have something working at my end :) Thanks for all the assistance